# Where does the power absorbed of this capacitor come from?

Tags: power, capacitor, capacitance

In my circuits book, the voltage across a capacitor is given as \$v(t)=100\cos({2\pi60t})\$.  Because \$i_{ab}=C\frac{d}{dt}v_{ab}\$, we naturally compute the current as \$i(t)=-120\pi\sin({2\pi60t})\$.  The book concurs.  It is easy to understand that for any given two-terminal component, \$p=vi\$, or in this case, \$p(t)=v(t)i(t)\$.  However, the book gives the answer to \$p(t)\$ as \$-18,850\sin({2\pi120t})\$.  However, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B100pi*cos%282pi60t%29%5D*%5B-120*pisin%282pi60t%29%5D) gives the link as \$-6000\pi^2sin(240\pi t)\$.

I have no idea where \$\pi\$ dissapears off to.  I have no idea where \$18,850\$ comes from.  I would be most grateful to anyone who could get me out of this jam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$p(t)=v(t)i(t)=-100\cdot120\pi\sin(2\pi 60t)\cos(2\pi 60t)=
-50\cdot 120\pi\sin(4\pi 60t)=\\=-6000\pi\sin(240\pi t)=-18850\sin(240\pi t)$$

I think you entered one factor of \$\pi\$ too many in WolframAlpha. Note that I used \$2\sin(x)\cos(x)=2\sin(2x)\$.

Comment: *Insert Picard Facepalm here* So its rounding!